# Codeigniter $this->input->post is always FALSE

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am trying to send an httpRequest to a codeigniter controller function. I am using the REST console to test the function . 
I am trying to send `3 POST` variables .

- UserName
- Email
- UserID

Here's the code to handle the request

```
public function NewUser()
{
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        $FID        = $this->input->post('UserID');
        $UserName   = $this->input->post('UserName');
        $Email      = $this->input->post('Email');
        echo "working";
        echo $FID;
        echo $UserName;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not working";
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. It always output's `not working`. When I change everything to `get`everything starts working fine.

What could be the issue ? Post Request is not working anywhere throughout this `codeigniter project`.

**EDIT**

I created a new script, with the following code.

```
<?php

  var_dump($_POST);
  echo $_POST['UserName'];
  echo $_POST['FacebookID'];
  echo $_POST['Email'];
  echo "********************************";
?>
```

It is saying `undefined index` . What could be the issue ? Please help. It works fine for `$_GET`

Comment: use `isset($_POST)` to check data.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` is `NULL`?

Comment: And you should also check with the name of you submit button isset($_POST['submitname'])

Comment: use `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);` to show post data

Comment: `var_dump` returns empty array like this `array(0) {}`

Comment: I guess, your issue about on `HttpRequest`.

Comment: user `isset($_REQUEST)` to check data

Comment: what's the result of `var_dump($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])`?   `REST REQUEST` is not a normal POST REQUEST

Comment: Do you have crsf protection enabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should try

`isset($_REQUEST)`
 or 
`!empty($_REQUEST)`

to check data is coming or not

Answer (score 13):

`$this->input->post()` is obliviously return the false because you are not mentioning the name of which value you want to retrieve using post.Make changes here in your code :

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

or

```
  if(!empty($_POST))
```

See [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

you can also do this:

```
if($this->input->post('username'))//username is the name of post variable
```

Comment: when I use if with `get` similarly as I've done above . It works. If you are saying that `$this->input->post()` will always return false than how is it working for `$this->input->get()` ?

Comment: than you need to specify the name of the variable post. see updated answer

Comment: @DesertP I am using `REST Console chrome extension` to send requests. The same thing is working flawlessly when I change variables to `get` instead of `post` .

Comment: you should check the response using var_dump($_REQUEST);

Comment: @Mj i think you receive  json data

Comment: OK I created a new script and still `$_POST` not working but `$_GET` is working . I think it is disabled in php. Can you tell me where to enable it ?

Answer (score 4):

To get the method in codeigniter 3 ([docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::method)) you can use the following code:

```
echo $this->input->method(TRUE); // Outputs: POST
echo $this->input->method(FALSE); // Outputs: post
echo $this->input->method(); // Outputs: post
```

example:

```
public function NewUser()
{
    if($this->input->method() === 'post')
    {
        $FID        = $this->input->post('UserID');
        $UserName   = $this->input->post('UserName');
        $Email      = $this->input->post('Email');
        echo "working";
        echo $FID;
        echo $UserName;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not working";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if( count($this->input->post()) > 0 )
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Due to using internationalization, URLs get redirected from user/login to user/en/login. When that redirect happens, the POST array gets lost.

I am not sure if this is your problem as well, but check if your page redirects after submission.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter we can check which `HttpRequest` it is using **2 below `Input` class' method :**

### 1. `server('REQUEST_METHOD')`

`$this->input->server()` is identical to Core PHP's `$_SERVER` variable.

example:

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'GET') {
   echo "It's GET Request";
} else if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
   echo "It's POST Request";
}
```

### 2. `method()`

Since Codeigniter 3 we can use `method()` also for checking request type.

> method([$upper = FALSE])

**Parameters:** 
$upper (bool) – Whether to return the request method name in ***upper or lower case***

**Returns:**    HTTP request method

**Return type:**    string

**explanantion:** It Returns the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, with the option to set it in uppercase or lowercase.

example:

```
echo $this->input->method(TRUE); // Outputs: POST
echo $this->input->method(FALSE); // Outputs: post
echo $this->input->method(); // Outputs: post
```